# Why does dispatch.fcgi show up in my address bar?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Would love any help on this. It's confusing me!

This started happening suddenly and I'm not really sure why. When you type my website address, `https://www.example.com`, into the address bar it redirect to `https://www.example.com/dispatch.fcgi/`. What is this `dispatch.fcgi` and why does it show up?

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you type my website address, `https://www.example.com`, into the address bar...

It's when you type `HTTP://www.example.com/` (note, HTTP, not HTTPS).

This is because your directives are in the wrong order... you are redirecting to HTTPS (HTTP to HTTPS redirect) *after* rewriting the request to `dispatch.fcgi/`. Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be the second rule. And your first rule that redirects from non-www to www should also redirect to HTTPS as well.

In other words, your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The additional *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) - that I've omitted here for brevity - are required when renewing your SSL certs.

> What is this `dispatch.fcgi`

This would seem to be your front-controller. (?)

Comment: Thank you. I actually figured it out after I posted this but this is the right answer for anyone having the same question. Give this person your upvotes.